# WebService Soap en java no me deja ingresar parámetros numéricos con más de 10 dígitos

Tags: java, webservice, soap

estoy haciendo un web service con java y el IDE de NetBeans, está enfocado en hacer una venta de un producto y descontar saldo en una tabla de una base de datos donde se guarda una tarjeta de débito/crédito, el problema que estoy teniendo es a la hora de testear el web service cuando implemento un número mayor a 10 dígitos, ¿alguien sabe que me puede estar pasado y cómo puedo ingresar números mayores a 10 dígitos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y pon el código en el formato que le corresponde, en modo texto, ya que puede que no a todos les enseñe la imágen

Answer (score 1):

El valor máximo de un entero (int o Integer) es 2,147,483,647. En la imagen se ve un número mayor a ese. Si realmente necesita permitir ingresar un número mayor a ese podría usar un `long` cuyo valor máximo es 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.